# NuxtJs - Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

Tags: authentication, cookies, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I'm a newbie in NuxtJs. I'm trying to implement an external API Call with axios which I get token and store it on cookie.  Everything works well in development. But when I try to run npm run generate it gives me errors that I don't know what to do.

When I delete nuxtSeverInit, npm run generate runs smoothly. And after some research, i think that nuxtServerInit that I'm using shouldn't be used. Can anyone please tell me how to make it work.

This is the first project in a new company, so I'm trying to prove myself. Please help me with it. Will you.

[Click here for image that shows the error that appears after npm run generate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8Fm2.png)

This is store/index.js file

```
  import Vuex from 'vuex'
  var cookieparser = require('cookieparser')

  const createStore = () => {
      return new Vuex.Store({
           state: {
              auth: null,
           },
           mutations: {
              update (state, data) {
                 state.auth = data
              }
           },
           actions: {
              nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
                     let accessToken = null
                     if (req.headers.cookie) {
                         var parsed = cookieparser.parse(req.headers.cookie)
                         if(parsed){
                            accessToken = parsed.auth
                         }

                      }  
                     commit('update', accessToken)
              },
           }
       })
   }
  export default createStore
```

middleware/authenticated.js  file

```
   export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
      // If the user is not authenticated
      if (!store.state.auth) {
        return redirect('/login')
      }
   }
```

middleware/notAuthenticated.js file

```
   export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
      // If the user is authenticated redirect to home page
      if (store.state.auth) {
         return redirect('/app/dashboard')
      }
    }
```

login.vue file

```
  validateBeforeSubmit() {
    this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
      if (result) {
        this.button_title = 'One moment ...';
        let submitted_user_data = {
          'username': this.emailAddress,
          'client_id': this.user_uuid,
          'password': this.password,
        }

        MerchantServices.do_user_login(submitted_user_data)
        .then(response => {
            let access_token = response.data.access_token;
            this.postLogin(access_token);

        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.$refs.invalid_credentials.open();
            this.button_title = 'Sign in'
        });
        return;
      }


    });
  },
  postLogin: function(access_token_val) {
    if(access_token_val != ''){
      setTimeout(() => {
        const auth = {
          accessToken: access_token_val
        }
        this.$store.commit('update', auth) 
        Cookie.set('auth', auth) 
        this.$refs.invalid_credentials.open();
        this.button_title = 'Sign in'
        this.$router.push('/app/dashboard')
      }, 1000)
    }else{
      alert('hello')
    }

  },
```

and the last user login api call which also returns the token.

```
    do_user_login(user){
          var user_details = 'username='+user.username+'&client_id='+ user.client_id +'&grant_type=password&password='+user.password+''
          return axios.post('myapiurl', user_details )
         .then(response =>  {
             return response;
          });
},
```

Comment: The [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) show that `req` is **Not available via `nuxt generate`**, which explains why it's undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Acording to [Nuxt Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context) **req** is not available on *nuxt generate*.
You should use *nuxt build* and than *nuxt start* after that.